# UITableView change first upper/lower unused cell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

Is it possible to modify the first "cell" under/over the "real" content?

Imagine this as the content or structure:

```
#0:[]
#1:[]
#2:[]
#3:[]
#4:[]
```

In this case, I would want to modify the cells with the number -1 and 5. But this should not affect the behaviour of the scrollbar. (e.g. not extending the scrollable content)

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Take a look at the facebook-refresh-cell. (Pull down the UITableView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
Instead of trying to modify the cells, just create your own Footer and Header cells and put everything you need there, it will always stay there without modifying the actual data cells
Look into

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
  {
  UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)] autorelease];
  view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

  return view;

  }

you can do the same for Footer view just change the viewForHeaderInSection to viewForFooterInSection

Comment: Thanks! To adjust the scrolling behaviour look at `contentInset`and `UIEdgeInsetsMake`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you want to change the content of cells off-screen.

You actually don't want to change the *cells* themselves, but rather, you want to change the *underlying data model* that provides the cells with their data. You can, of course, do this at any time.

You shouldn't be trying to get at the `UITableCell` objects themselves.

Comment: Exactly. But how can I can change for example the backgroundView property of an off-screen-cell. (Like the first refresh cell in the facebook-app if you pull the tableview down)

Comment: In general you shouldn't worry about the appearance of off-screen cells. Their appearance only needs to be configured when they are going to appear on-screen, and the underlying framework will ask you to do just that when it calls the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: But if I "add" another cell above and below the normal cells, those newly created will also be considered As scrollable content.

Comment: @Fscheidl I don't understand. What do you mean by "normal" cell?